# input element overshadows the click button - Python, selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to send a PNR and then click on the submit button. The PNR gets correctly filled in but the submit button is not getting clicked. So I commented on the `send_key()` line and checked if the submit button is getting clicked and it gets clicked. But when I send the PNR value and subsequently click the submit button it doesn't work.

Below is the snapshot of the same:
[image: When the send_keys() is commented result]

and below is the code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("link")

time.sleep(10)

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/a[6]/div/div[2]/div[1]'))))

#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='PNR']"))).send_keys("PNR")

WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[16]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div'))).click()
```

Can anyone help me with how to make the submit button work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that keeps on clicking in an infinite loop until the next popup or screen is displayed.

Code:

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/")

button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='GST Invoice']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='PNR']"))).send_keys('AGQR8U')
submit_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Submit']")))
while True:
    submit_btn.click()
    try:
        if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='PNR']").is_displayed():
            print('PNR is displayed')
            break
        else:
            print('PNR is not displayed yet. Keep retrying submit click')
    except:
        pass
```

**Import:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
PNR is displayed
```

[image]

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: Well, I tried to click 2-3 times manually and it did work so I automated the same.

Comment: How long did it take to print the PNR displayed message? As I have run the same and it has not displayed the message yet.

Comment: It took a bit of time.. but this will work for real. You can decrease time in webdriverwait command and see if that helps with time optimization.

Comment: Isn't there another way? It takes too long to complete.

Comment: In that case we will have to remove try and except block and just perform click 5 times in a loop and exit from infinite loop.

Comment: Is it working for you? How did you do it?

Comment: Nope, the above solution is best for your problem. Since that's not a generic situation where click does not get triggered.

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: Well, it was working 10 hours ago for me and for you as well. I don't see any reason It should not work now.

Comment: The 5 times click in a loop is not working after removal of try-except.